# How do I assign a number to a word in a list?

Tags: python, list

This is my current progress. I'm somewhat new to Python and I'm kind of lost. I don't really know exactly how to solve the problem and I apologies if the title is somewhat misleading. I'll try and explain my problem as best I can.

---

The output needs to be this in list form:

```
"WHAT", "IS", "MINE", "IS", "YOURS", "AND", "WHAT", "IS", "YOURS", "IS", "MINE"

"1", "2", "3", "2", "4", "5", "1", "2", "4", "2", "3"
```

`"1"` is `"WHAT"`, `"2"` is `"IS"`... and so on. If the word appears more than once, it will remain the same number.

---

Code

```
sentence = "WHAT IS MINE IS YOURS AND WHAT IS YOURS IS MINE";

sentence = sentence.lower();

sentence = sentence.split();

uniqueWord = [];

store = [];

for i in sentence:
    if i not in uniqueWord:
        uniqueWord.append(i);

lengthOfUniqueWord = len(uniqueWord);

print(sentence);

print(uniqueWord);

for i in range(lengthOfUniqueWord):
    i = str(i+1);
    store.append(i);

print(store);

for positions in enumerate(uniqueWord, 1):
     print(positions);
```

---

Output

```
['what', 'is', 'mine', 'is', 'yours', 'and', 'what', 'is', 'yours', 'is', 'mine']
['what', 'is', 'mine', 'yours', 'and']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
(1, 'what')
(2, 'is')
(3, 'mine')
(4, 'yours')
(5, 'and')
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  See the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about how to get help most effectively.  Would you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37910190/edit) to include the output you are *currently* getting in addition to the output you want (already included)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sentence = "WHAT IS MINE IS YOURS AND WHAT IS YOURS IS MINE";    
sentence = sentence.lower();
sentence = sentence.split();

uniqueWord = [];

for i in sentence:
    if i not in uniqueWord:
        uniqueWord.append(i);

for word in sentence:
    print uniqueWord.index(word) + 1
```

Here it is the link to the documentation of [`index`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 0):

While others also typed there answers ;-) I came up with - hope it contains further hints on Python coding also:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function


def word_indexer(text):
    """Split the text in words maintaining order and return two
    aligned lists: 1) the words all in sequence, and 2) the matching
    unique 1-based case insensitive index (insert based rank)."""

    words_in_order = text.split()
    word_index = []
    unique_word_rank = {}
    rank = 1
    for word in words_in_order:
        normalized_word = word.lower()
        if normalized_word not in unique_word_rank:
            unique_word_rank[normalized_word] = rank
            rank += 1
        word_index.append(unique_word_rank[normalized_word])

    return words_in_order, word_index


def main():
    """Do the word indexing."""
    sentence = "WHAT IS MINE IS YOURS AND WHAT IS YOURS IS MINE"
    words_in_order, word_index = word_indexer(sentence)
    # print as in question in two lines:
    print(words_in_order)
    print(word_index)
    # to display like a table:
    for ndx, word in zip(word_index, words_in_order):
        print(ndx, word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gives on my system (with Python 2.7.11 but also runs with Python 3.5.1):

```
['WHAT', 'IS', 'MINE', 'IS', 'YOURS', 'AND', 'WHAT', 'IS', 'YOURS', 'IS', 'MINE']
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3]
1 WHAT
2 IS
3 MINE
2 IS
4 YOURS
5 AND
1 WHAT
2 IS
4 YOURS
2 IS
3 MINE
```

Hope this helps - and happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for licensing your contributions under a broader license!  I have also done so and am always encouraged when I see others making site users' lives easier! :)

Comment: Great meta feedback :-) Not that I consider any of my co(de|n)tributions important myself, but allowing others to copy and paste answers without fear, is to me an important if not fundamental aspect of a Q&A coding site. After all we encourage the people asking to provide  copy and paste ready to run code ...

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `count` iterator, that only increments if a new word is inserted into dict `d`. Build the final list from the matching number of each word:

```
from itertools import count

sentence = "WHAT IS MINE IS YOURS AND WHAT IS YOURS IS MINE"  
s =  sentence.split()
c = count(1)
d = {}

for word in s:
    if word.lower() not in d:
         d[word.lower()] = next(c)

result = [str(d[word.lower()]) for word in s]
# ['1', '2', '3', '2', '4', '5', '1', '2', '4', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method of achieving the same goal:

```
sentence = "WHAT IS MINE IS YOURS AND WHAT IS YOURS IS MINE".lower().split()
uniqueWord = list(set(sentence))

print(sentence);
print(uniqueWord);

store = [uniqueWord.index(x) for x in sentence]

print(store);
```